# DataSnapshot's getValue method returns a null instance of my class when it shouldn't. Adding fields to my Class breaks my code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So first I'll show my code, then I'll give some specific info about the circumstances of my issue.

```
dbRef = database.getReference().child("Users").child(emailKey);
    dbRefL = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    /* This executes when the Activity starts. It sets email1 to the logged in User's email add
     * and it sets sellerName to the logged in User's username. Should only execute once but doesn't
     * really matter if that's not true;
     */
    dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserInfo userinfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInfo.class);
            email1 =  userinfo.email;
            sellerName = userinfo.username;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

My error is as follows:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String semicolon.foodbnb.UserInfo.email' on a null object reference
                                                                       at semicolon.foodbnb.CreateListingActivity2$1.onDataChange

So I get a nullPointerException when I know for a fact that Firebase shouldn't be null for the node Users>emailKey>email.

Something valuable to note is that I only started getting this issues when I make changes to the UserInfo clsas. I don't see how it should affect this though.

Going through other Stack Overflow posts made me think that it's grabbing the wrong UserInfo class when I start up this Activity. (This listener is located in the OnCreate method).

I just want to access the currently logged in User's email and username (both fields under User > emailKey > username/email

Here is my very simple UserInfo class.

```
public class UserInfo {
public String username;
public String email;
public String password;
public String zipcode;
public String creditcard;
public String phone;
public String profilePicture;

//No arg ctor
public UserInfo() {}

//5 arg ctor -- every field is initialized
public UserInfo(String un, String email, String pw, String zip, String cc, String phone) {
    username = un;
    password = pw;
    this.email = email;
    zipcode = zip;
    creditcard = cc;
    this.phone = phone;
    profilePicture = "";
}

public UserInfo(String un, String email, String pw, String zip, String cc, String phone, String picture) {
    username = un;
    password = pw;
    this.email = email;
    zipcode = zip;
    creditcard = cc;
    this.phone = phone;
    profilePicture = picture;
}

//getters

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public String getZipcode() {
    return zipcode;
}

public String getCreditcard() {
    return creditcard;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public String getProfilePicture() {
    return profilePicture;
}
```

}

This nullpointer issue appeared when I tried to add an arrayList to my UserInfo class. Now the issue has reappeared when I added a Profile Picture field. Why does added fields break my code?

EDIT: If I log in with an older User account that DOESN'T have the profile Picture field, there is no nullPointer issue. If I log into a newer account WITH the profile picture field there IS  a nullpointer issue

Answer (score 2):

You UserInfo model class should be the same as the data you read from Firebase. 
If you want to add new fields to it , update your Firebase database scheme to include the new field and it will work.

Comment: If it does not correspond to your model inside Firebase, GSON cannot parse the json response into your specific class object and then return null. Thats why your object userinfo is null.

Comment: But how does one update your firebase database scheme? When I create a user I dynamically add all the fields under it to firebase

Comment: If you create a user with the new model it should work , just make sure to clear up all the old entries first.

Comment: Thanks Hristo. I didn't know I had to delete all my old User objects too. I don't quite understand, but now when I register a new User the code works.